# Swift: Alamofire Value of type 'Self' (Request) has no member 'responseJSON' extension

Tags: swift, alamofire

I created an extension of Request here is the code below:

```
extension Request {

    public func responseIDEA(completionHandler: (AnyObject?, String?) -> Void) -> Self {
            self.responseJSON() { response in
                if response.result.error != nil {
                    completionHandler (nil, response.result.error!.localizedDescription)
                }else {
                  completionHandler(response.result.value?.valueForKey("Data"), response.result.value?.valueForKey("Message") as? String)
                }
        }
    } 
}
```

But I have this error:

> Value of type 'Self' has no member 'responseJSON'

Why I can't get responseJSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`responseJSON` is declared in two extensions - one in `DataRequest`, another in `DownloadRequest`.

Since `Request` is a superclass of both of those classes, `Request` does not have a `responseJSON` method.

Create two extensions for `DataRequest` and `DownloadRequest`:

```
extension DataRequest {

    public func responseIDEA(completionHandler: (AnyObject?, String?) -> Void) -> Self {
            self.responseJSON() { response in
                if response.result.error != nil {
                    completionHandler (nil, response.result.error!.localizedDescription)
                }else {
                  completionHandler(response.result.value?.valueForKey("Data"), response.result.value?.valueForKey("Message") as? String)
                }
        }
    } 
}

extension DownloadRequest {

    public func responseIDEA(completionHandler: (AnyObject?, String?) -> Void) -> Self {
            self.responseJSON() { response in
                if response.result.error != nil {
                    completionHandler (nil, response.result.error!.localizedDescription)
                }else {
                  completionHandler(response.result.value?.valueForKey("Data"), response.result.value?.valueForKey("Message") as? String)
                }
        }
    } 
}
```

Or just write one of them if you only ever need one of them.